# Django faceting sub-categories via foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a list of items that have a 'top category' and a 'middle category', eventually there will be a 'lower category' but not right now. For example **Electronics > Laptops**, respectively.

I want to dynamically facet on this categories, so laptops will display under electronics etc.

Any thoughts on how I can acheive this? Currenty I have the 'Top Categories' faceting correctly.

models.py

```
class mid_category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Mid Categories'
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class top_category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Top Categories'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    mid_cat = models.ForeignKey(mid_category, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


# Item
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    retailer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=800, unique=True, default='')
    sku = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    barcode = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    featured = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, choices=FEATURED_CHOICES, default='NO')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    top_cat = models.ForeignKey(top_category)
    mid_cat = models.ForeignKey(mid_category, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

search_indexes.py

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from haystack import indexes
from haystack.fields import CharField

from decimal import Decimal

from .models import Product, top_category

class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(
        document=True, use_template=True,
        template_name='/home/wilkinj33/bargainforest/bargainforestenv/motorclass/templates/search/indexes/product_text.txt'
        )

    title = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')
    retailer = indexes.CharField(model_attr='retailer', faceted=True)
    price = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='price', faceted=True)
    barcode = indexes.CharField(model_attr='barcode')
    topCat = indexes.CharField(model_attr='top_cat', faceted=True)
    midCat = indexes.CharField(model_attr='mid_cat', faceted=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Product

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(timestamp__lte=timezone.now())
```

results.html

```
            <h3 class="widget-title">Shop Categories</h3>
            <ul>
             {% if facets.fields.topCat %}
                {% for top_category in facets.fields.topCat %}
              <li class="has-children"><a href="#" onclick="return onFacetChangeApplied();">{{top_category.0|cut:" "}}</a><span>(1138)</span>
                <ul>


                </ul>
              </li>
                {% endfor %}
              {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit weird to structure your models this way.

In your current code, you seem to be doing this the wrong way around. Instead of the middle category referencing its parent, the top category tries to reference its children, which is impossible as a foreign key can only point to one object.

If you want to do it in your current code you need something like more like this:

```
class TopCategory(models.Model):
    name = ...

class MiddleCategory(models.Model):
    name = ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey(TopCategory)
```

Better still would be something more generic, like this tree structure, that could handle any number of levels of categories:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = ...
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Then you can filter on a parent category something like:

```
`Product.objects.filter(category__parent=top_category)
```

assuming you have a `Product` model with an FK to `Category`.

Even better you should probably use something like [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) or [django-treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard) to make your tree more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'm going to read up on the design of models and sort them out.
Any thoughts on faceting?

Comment: Thanks, I've changed my models and they're much better. Still no luck on the faceting front, I've been through the docs too.